# Passing $routeParams between controllers via dependency injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I would like to know how to pass a variable within the scope of this controller to another controller. What i want to do is take the vm.search (searchParameters) and pass it to another controller.

///

(function () {
    'use strict';

```
var controllerId = 'GroupMaintenanceBrowsePlansCtrl';

angular.module('myApp').controller(controllerId, ['$scope', 'RenewalGroupDataService', 'logger', Controller]);

function Controller($scope, datacontext, logger) {
    logger = logger.forSource(controllerId);
    var logError = logger.logError;
    var logSuccess = logger.logSuccess;
    var logWarning = logger.logWarning;

    var vm = {};
    $scope.vm = vm;

    vm.getPlans = getPlans;
    vm.plans;
    vm.loadingPlans = false;


    vm.pageSize = 100;

    function getPlans(searchParameters) {
        vm.loadingPlans = true; vm.search = searchParameters;

        datacontext.getAssignedPlans(searchParameters, vm.pageSize).then(function (plans) {
            vm.plans = plans;

      //Compares which columns are being populated for choosing which headings to show
        if (vm.search.MchNumber != null 
            ||vm.search.ContractNumber != null 
            || vm.search.PlanCode != null)
        {

            vm.detail = true;
        }

        if (vm.search.DivisionName != null
            || vm.search.PoolName != null
            || vm.search.SubpoolName != null
            || vm.search.RenewalGroupName != null)
        {
            vm.detail = false;
        }

            //Sets values to NULL after every search is performed
       vm.search.MchNumber =
       vm.search.ContractNumber =
       vm.search.PlanCode =
       vm.search.DivisionName =
       vm.search.PoolName =
       vm.search.SubpoolName =
       vm.search.RenewalGroupName = null;

        }).finally(function () { vm.loadingPlans = false; });
    }
};
```

})();

Comment: Hey man, you should look into using an Angular factory. You can use the factory to get or create any data you want and then you can inject it into any controller you want. Take a look at the docs for it. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers. Also this video explains it pretty well. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=74l16B992dQ

Answer (score 0):

To use a value between 2 controllers you could use a service which both controllers inject.

e.g.

```
root.service("MyService", function () {});
```

Inject `MyService` into each controller.  Then both controllers will be using the same instance (as services are singletons) so anything you change on that service will be shared.

You can also place the service on `$scope` and use template binding with it.  But in your case I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: I want to go between the controller i have above and this one:


myApp.controller('MchController', function ($scope, $routeParams, mchService, CustomerDataService, EntityInfoService, RatesDataService, BrowsePlansService) {
    $scope.routeParams = {
        type: $routeParams.Type,
        id: $routeParams.Id
    };

    //Properties associated with data
    $scope.visible = {
        experience: true,
        persistency: true,
    }

    var vm = {};
    $scope.vm = vm; //local scope to MchController
    vm.type = $routeParams.Type;
    vm.id = $routeParams.Id;}}

Comment: Do you mean you are navigating between pages? or are the controllers on the same page?

Comment: I'm staying on the same page, i'm just using different controllers with multiple different services. I want my MchController's $routeParame.Id to be passed from my GroupMaintenanceBrowsePlansCtrl

Comment: Then this does apply.  Create a service to hold the data.  Do you require a notification on the other controller if so use $watch on the particular value and use $on on the other contrller.  The service will need adding to the scope to do this.

Comment: Everytime i try to hold the data via a service i keep getting an error saying it's undefined. Are there particular steps to passing? I want it to be globally available within the controller i'm passing to (MchController)